# compare two dataGridView cell with date value?

Tags: c#

in my c# windows form i have a **dataGridView** that loads the data from a table,

The `dataGridView` has **8 columns** two of them have **date** value
`borrow_date` and `return_date`.

I want to compare the of that two columns if the date of any `return_date` cell is greater that the date of `borrow_date` cell, make the background of that cell red or make it's fore color red.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you

```
<asp:GridView ID="ctlGridView" runat="server" OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated" />


protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   { 
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    Object ob = drv["return_date"];
    Object ob1 = drv["borrow_date"];



    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(ob) && !Convert.IsDBNull(ob1) )
    {
       DateTime date1return_date;
        DateTime date2borrow_date;

         if (DateTime.TryParse(ob.ToString(), out date1return_date) && 
                   DateTime.TryParse(ob1.ToString(), out date2borrow_date))
         {
             if (date1return_date > date2borrow_date)
             {
                 TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1]; // Get your required cell
                 cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
             }
         }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` to compare date.

[DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by different ways:

1 Looping the entire `grid` once all data was loaded

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows) 
     if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["borrow_date"].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["return_date"].Value)) 
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
     }
```

2 doing it as each row gets loaded.

```
private void gridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
   if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["borrow_date"].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["return_date"].Value)) 
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
     }
}
```

Comment: grid is a datagridview? ... i use your code but it does not work?

Comment: Yes, grid should be the name of your grid. About the events, you need to add the event handler to the datagrid. I don't have a tutorial link right now, but you can click on the grid go to the Properties panel, and click on the lighting bolt (Events); all the events have a self-explanatory name. good luck.

Comment: you gridView1_RowPrePaint? i add your code to this event ... but also have an error i use your second method this is my code   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                } ... 5 and 7 is the index of the two column

Comment: Well, as you didn't use sample code (as you should, i copy-pasted mine). If you use sample code, all suggestions will be upon there. Also, the comparision should be done with DateTime class, as @Francois states in his answer.

Comment: i don't understand you sorry